# FAQ Show/Hide Expanding Answers

Tags: javascript, show-hide, expand

I have a list of 12 FAQs, but I only want to display the top 5 until the user clicks a "Show More" button.  I got that part working, but in doing so it expands the answers to the new 7 FAQs it is showing.  I want to keep the answers hidden until the user clicks the question, but am not sure how to go about it.  I'm modifying someone else's code, I didn't write it originally.

Example:
[code]http://63.246.25.145/surety-bonds/contract-bonds/performance_bond.htm[/code]

JS:
[code]
//faq question answer expand

```
$("#faqs .question").click(function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass("open"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("open");
        $("#answer_"+$(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]).slideUp().removeClass("open")
    }
    else
    {
        $("#faqs .question.open").removeClass("open");
        $("#faqs .answer.open").slideUp().removeClass("open");
        $(this).addClass("open");
        $("#answer_"+$(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]).slideDown().addClass("open")
    }
});
```

//Bond page faq show/hide

```
$("#faqlistholder5").each(   //count 10 since question <li>s and answer <li>s
    function()
    {
        var f=$("ul",this);

        if(f.children("li").size()<=10)
            return;

        var u=f.children("li:gt(9)",this).hide();
        var m="VIEW MORE &raquo";

        f.append($('<div id="viewMore" class="toggler"><a id="viewmorebuttonFAQ" class="button">'+m+"</a></div>").toggle(
            function()
            {
                u.show();
                $("#viewmorebuttonFAQ").html("VIEW LESS &raquo")
            },
                function()
                {
                    u.hide();$("#viewmorebuttonFAQ").html("VIEW MORE &raquo")
                }))
    });
```

[/code]

Can anyone provide me some much needed guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
$("#faqs .answer").hide().removeClass("open");
```

after *u.show();*

---

```
function()
        {
            u.show();
            $("#faqs .answer").hide().removeClass("open");
            $("#viewmorebuttonFAQ").html("VIEW LESS &raquo")
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that portion of code is executed? Try to add a console.log or an alert()

Comment: Confirmed.  See example below.Example: [code]http://63.246.25.145/surety-bonds/contract-bonds/performance_bond.htm[/code]

Comment: I edited the code. (Anyway I don't understand why you use $("#faqlistholder5").each for a function that should run once)